# C - Parse file and write to separate files based on the last field

Tags: c

The software intends to read from a csv styled file (it's delimited by space not by a comma) and split the initial file into two new ones. The two files are determined by the last field, which is a binary value. As it stands, it currently reads the file character by character. I want it to recognize the space, and only run the individual character check on the very last field. To my understanding, strtok() will come in handy, but I'm struggling to find a way to incorporate that into the existing software.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
/*
 * C program to parse a file, and split it into two based on the final line of input
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


/* Function declarations */
int isMale(signed char _line);
int isFemale(signed char _line);


int isMale(signed char _line)
{

}

int isFemale(signed char _line)
{

}



int main()
{
    /* File pointer to hold reference to different files */

    FILE * fPtrIn,      // Input file
         * fPtrMale,    // Males of school age 
         * fPtrFemale,  // Females of school age
         * fPtrMisc;    // Data not within the given parameters
    
    // current_char is the current character being read
    // success stores the read status
    char current_char;
    int success;

    // Open all files to perform read/write.
    fPtrIn       = fopen("data/example.txt", "r");
    fPtrMale     = fopen("data/males.txt" , "w");
    fPtrFemale   = fopen("data/females.txt"  , "w");
    fPtrMisc     = fopen("data/erroneus.txt", "w");


    // fopen() return NULL if unable to open file in given mode. 
    if(fPtrIn == NULL || fPtrMale == NULL || fPtrFemale == NULL || fPtrMisc == NULL)
    {
        // Unable to open file, exit software 
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
        printf("Please check whether file exists and you have read/write privilege.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    // File open success message
    printf("File opened successfully. \n\n");

    // Read an integer and store read status in success.
    while (fscanf(fPtrIn, "%d", &current_char) != -1)
    {
        // Write each one to separate file
        if (isMale(current_char))
            fprintf(fPtMale, "%d\n", current_char);
        else if (isFemale(current_char))
            fprintf(fPtrFemale, "%d\n", current_char);
        else
            fprintf(fPtrMisc, "%d\n", current_char);

    }


    // Done with all files, hence close all.
    fclose(fPtrIn);
    fclose(fPtrMale);
    fclose(fPtrFemale);
    fclose(fPtrMisc);

    printf("Data written to files successfully.");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(fPtrIn, "%d", &current_char)` invokes *undefined behavior* because `char*` is passed where `int*` is expected. Actually this is dangerous because `char` has fewer space than `int` in typical environment.

Comment: You should 1. read lines via `fgets()` 2. parse fields via `sscanf()` (or `strtok()`, but you should copy the string (line) because it modifies the input buffer) 3. judge and output according to the parsed fields.

Comment: If the number of fields in one line varies, using `strtok()` seems better.

Comment: There are quite a lot of examples of how to use strtok and how to parse csv files here. Have you read any of those questions?

Comment: `The two files are determined by the last field, which is a binary value`. What do you mean by `binary` ?

Comment: Well, it's either Male or Female

Comment: The whole word and not `'m'` or `'f'`? (add sample line of input to question at end indented by 4-spaces)

Comment: The format is as follows:

First, Last, Age, Gender

Comment: And it's just an M or an F

Comment: See comment below @MikeCAT answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should

1. Read lines via `fgets()`
2. Copy the line read because `strtok()` will modify original buffer.
3. parse fields via `strtok()`
4. Judge and output according to the parsed field.

```
// hoping that too long lines won't come
char line[102400], line_parse[102400];

// Read an integer and store read status in success.
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fPtrIn) != NULL)
{
    char *last_field, *ret;
    // Copy the line for parsing
    strcpy(line_parse, line);
    // Separate the line into tokens
    last_field = ret = strtok(line_parse, " ");
    while (ret != NULL)
    {
        last_field = ret;
        ret = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    // Get the first character of the last field
    if (last_field == NULL) current_char = '\0'; else current_char = last_field[0];
    // Write each one to separate file
    if (isMale(current_char))
        fputs(line, fPtrMale);
    else if (isFemale(current_char))
        fputs(line, fPtrFemale);
    else
        fputs(line, fPtrMisc);

}
```

Comment: No need for `strtok` nor `line_parse` array.  `char *p = strrchr(line, ' '); current_char = p ? p[1] : line[0];` is enough to determine the value of `current_char`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The `last &&` is redundant. Also, this approach will fail when the last field doesn't consist of a single character, such as `male` or `female`, which is not clear in the OP's question.

Comment: @MikeCAT - Thanks so much for your help here buddy, managed to get it working now. Few more tweaks of some logic my end and it should all be working perfectly. All the best!

Comment: @LewisFarnworth -- don't forget to **validate** each critical step -- including *close-after-write*, e.g. `if (fclose(fPtrMale) != EOF) perror ("fclose-fPtrMale");`

Comment: `size_t last = strcspn(line,"\r\n"); if (last && line[last-1] == 'M')` ... is probably the simplest way to pick off the last character in the line.  The `last` test is required.